# Fetching Data from more than 1000 rows

Tags: sql

I have got a file that has 69297 records of one-column type. I need to place them in sql-query inside the in clause.
Since, it's a known fact that the "in" clause works with 1000 records at a time, how may I retrieve this(69297) much amount of data in a less cumbersome manner?

Comment: update your question and add a proper data sample please

Comment: And you need to specify which SQL vendor you're using

Comment: "it's a known fact that the "in" clause works with 1000 records at a time".  Really?

Answer (score 1):

Create a table and insert all the values in the table. Then use the table as inner join to fetch the records from target table(after changing the SQL script). This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a temporary table with one column and store the 69297 rows into that table.
2. Use the temporary table in your IN clause as below.
3. Drop the temporary table created in the first step.

Comment: Good answer, except it would no longer need to be an "IN" clause (which is computationally expensive). An inner join would do the same job and make better use of DB query optimizations.